# Why iPad app build fails in xcode with a error creating temporary directory?

Tags: xcode, ipad, build-error

I'm using Xcode 4.6, and trying to run a simple app in iPad 6.1 Simulator, build fails with error message

```
mkdir: /Users/chakradar.r/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dino-eddkhtnsnrlgwjgqnaceabrxcjsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dino.app/wwwof: File exists
```

that is a temporary directory, i even tried building it after removing the directory, it again fails with a similar message.

Once my Xcode went unresponsive so I force quit Xcode while this application was running, I suspect that could be the reason for the failure. Error message is not helping, how can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 4):

While I don't know the exact reason you're getting this error. Here are some generic steps that you can try in these situations:

- In the simulator app go to *'iOS Simulator'* (in the top menu), choose *'Reset Content and Settings...'*
- In Xcode go to *'Product'* then *'Clean'*
- In Xcode go to *'Window'* then *'Organizer'*, click on the *'Projects'* icon on the top, find your project in the list on the left and click *'Delete...'* beside the *'Derived Data'*
- Restart your Mac (Yes, sometimes this really resolves some issues)

You can try any of these options individually or all of them.

Comment: Build failed, iOS Simulator was not even opened, did every step except first, didn't help, i created a fresh phonegap project, even that failed, do you think xcode could have been broken?

Comment: Reinstalled Xcode, and the problem is fixed, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I too even don't know the exact root cause but

Killed both Xcode and Simulator and ran the app again and it started working for me.